# Python script.py file url parameter

Tags: python, url, distribution, setup.py

I am very new to python and am learning to create python distributions. I have realized that setup.py file is an essential part of this process. I was wondering however what the value of the 'url:' field in the setup.py script was supposed to address? As in what is the url that I provide to the 'url' field mean? And what url should I provide if I want to upload my module to pypi.

I apologize for the simplicity of the question but this particular topic doesn't seem to be addressed much in the python documentation.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's the url to the homepage of your project (for example, the github page, or some site you have set up for it).

You can get a full list of the metadata in [distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data).